# Numeric values of WinHTTP constants (eg. WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT)

Tags: vb6, winhttp, winhttprequest

I need to set this property for a WinHttp request...

```
BOOL fRet = WinHttpSetOption(hRequest,
                             WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT,
                             WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT,
                             0);
```

But from within an old VB application.  I can access the method but can't use the constants.

I can use this to access the method from VB...

```
Declare Function WinHttpSetOption Lib "winhttp.dll" _ 
(ByVal hInternet As Variant, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As Byte, ByVal dwBufferLength As Integer) _ 
As Boolean
```

And then call it like so...

```
Call WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, 0);
```

But have to replace the constants `WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT` and `WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT` with the correct numbers, or figure out how to import them.

After I long google search, I think  `WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT` is 47 but can't find **`WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT`** anywhere.

Many thanks

Comment: In PowerBASIC it's defined as ```%WINHTTP_NO_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT = %NULL```, where ```%NULL = 0```. tl;dr it's zero.

Comment: Many thanks! Can you confirm if WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT is defined as 47?

Comment: Yes, it is. BTW, the PowerBASIC definitions are a direct translation of the VC++ header file _WinHttp.h_. If you can get hold of a copy it - everything is in there.